# ExpiredToken when calling ListAccessKeys operation when running mock test

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, boto3

I'm fairly new to running tests and still learning python in general. I am trying to run some tests on a function in another python file called handler.py. When I run my tests I get an error about an expired token. I want avoid changing any code in the existing python file, if possible. My handler.py file is as follows:

```
import logging
import json
import boto3
import base64
import datetime
import os
from datetime import date
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

iam_client = boto3.client("iam")

environment = os.environ["ENVIRONMENT"]
notification_lambda_arn = os.environ["NOTIFICATION_LAMBDA"]
notification_sender_address = os.environ["NOTIFICATION_SENDER"]
platform_dl = os.environ["PLATFORM_CONTACT"]
key_rotation_dl_tag_name = os.environ["KEY_ROTATION_DL_TAG_NAME"]
messageprefix = f"Key rotation for {environment}: "

def create_key(uname):
    try:
        IAM_UserName = uname
        keys = iam_client.list_access_keys(UserName=IAM_UserName)["AccessKeyMetadata"]
        logger.info(f"Keys for IAM user {uname} - {keys}")
        inactive_keys = list(filter(lambda x: x["Status"] == "Inactive", keys))
        if len(keys) > 1:
            if len(inactive_keys) > 0:
                inactive_key = inactive_keys[0]["AccessKeyId"]
                logger.info(
                    f"Deleting inactive key '{inactive_key}' for IAM user {uname} to free up a slot for the new key creation."
                )
                iam_client.delete_access_key(
                    UserName=IAM_UserName, AccessKeyId=inactive_key
                )
            else:
                raise Exception(
                    f"Cannot create a new key for IAM user '{IAM_UserName}', because it already has 2 active keys. To fix the error, make at least one key inactive."
                )

        response = iam_client.create_access_key(UserName=IAM_UserName)
        AccessKey = response["AccessKey"]["AccessKeyId"]
        SecretKey = response["AccessKey"]["SecretAccessKey"]
        json_data = json.dumps({"AccessKey": AccessKey, "SecretKey": SecretKey})
        # check if secret exists
        secret_exists = False
        try:
            secretmanager.describe_secret(SecretId=IAM_UserName)
            secret_exists = True
        except ClientError:
            pass
        if not secret_exists:
            secretmanager.create_secret(Name=IAM_UserName)

        secmanagerv = secretmanager.put_secret_value(
            SecretId=IAM_UserName, SecretString=json_data
        )
        return "OK", {
            "subject": f"{messageprefix} New Key created for IAM user '{IAM_UserName}'",
            "body": messageprefix
            + "New access key ("
            + AccessKey
            + ") has been created for IAM User "
            + IAM_UserName
            + ". Secret key is "
            + SecretKey
            + ". You need to change the new key pair within the next 10 days before the previous key is deactivated.",
        }
    except ClientError as e:
        logger.error(e)
```

There's a lot more functions in the overall code, but the above is the main one i'm testing now. I'm getting the error on the line with `keys = iam_client.list_access_keys(UserName=IAM_UserName)["AccessKeyMetadata"]` when I run pytest the exact error i'm getting is `An error occurred (ExpiredToken) when calling the ListAccessKeys operation: The security token included in the request is expired`

And the test I am trying to run against this function is below:

```
import sys
# adding folder1/folder2/folder3 to the system path
sys.path.insert(1, 'folder1/folder2/folder3')
import unittest
import boto3
from datetime import datetime
from botocore.stub import Stubber
from unittest import mock
from unittest.mock import patch


with mock.patch.dict('os.environ',{'ENVIRONMENT': 'us-east-1',
                                   'NOTIFICATION_LAMBDA': '',
                                   'NOTIFICATION_SENDER': '',
                                   'PLATFORM_CONTACT': '',
                                   'KEY_ROTATION_DL_TAG_NAME': ''
                                   }):
    import handler
    

class TestLambda(unittest.TestCase):
    def tests_create_key(self):
        client = boto3.client('iam')
        stubber = Stubber(client)
        
        # expected response from boto3 iam client list_access_keys()
        expected_response = {u'AccessKeyMetadata': [
                                {
                                    'UserName': 'testUser',
                                    'AccessKeyId': 'AKIA111111111EXAMPLE',
                                    'Status': 'Active',
                                    'CreateDate': datetime(2015, 1, 1)
                                }
                                                    ]                                
                            }
        
        # stubbed iam client call to list_access_keys results in expected_response
        stubber.add_response('list_access_keys', expected_response, {'UserName': 'testUser'})
             
        # patching boto3 attribute of handler.py with stubber
        with patch('handler.boto3') as mock_boto3:
            with stubber:
                mock_boto3.client.return_value = client
                stubber.activate()
                # call to create_key in handler.py
                list_access_key_response = handler.create_key('testUser')
                self.assertEqual(list_access_key_response, expected_response)
```

When running these tests and trying to debug it, I think the issue could possibly be `iam_client` from handler.py being initialized again after `stubber.activate()` in my test file. When I run through debugging it, all of the attributes in my test file look fine, but then when it jumps into handler.py that's where it seems to go back to normal. If I place `iam_client = boto3.client("iam")` in my create_key function it works, but I would like to refrain from altering the code in handler.py and see if I can adjust my test to work around this.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you invoke a lambda function it will assume the execution role and garner new temporary security keys/tokens to be able to make authenticated calls on your behalf.  If you utilize these keys "outside" of the lambda function you cannot control the session duration.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-intro-execution-role.html

When you instantiate the boto3 client outside of the lambda handler you are effectively using the keys "outside" of the lambda function and after approximately an hour the keys will expire.  If your lambda is busy enough to force the underlying microVM to recycle, you wouldn't notice the issue or would only notice it intermittently.

The solution is to move your client call within the handler, or add logic that checks that the client is valid and recreates it when the keys expire.